# How can scrape the team names and goals from this site into a table? Ive been trying a few different methods but can't quite figure it out

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy, data-science

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.hockey-reference.com/leagues/NHL_2021_games.html"
page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
results = soup.find(id="all_games")

table = soup.find('div', attrs = {'id':'div_games'}) 
print(table.prettify())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the table not the div to print the table:

```
table = soup.find('table', attrs = {'id':'games'}) 
print(table.prettify())
```

---

Or use `pandas.read_html()` to get the table and transform into a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.read_html('https://www.hockey-reference.com/leagues/NHL_2021_games.html', attrs={'id':'games'})[0].iloc[:,:5]
```

Output:

| Date | Visitor | G | Home | G.1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-13 | St. Louis Blues | 4 | Colorado Avalanche | 1 |
| 2021-01-13 | Vancouver Canucks | 5 | Edmonton Oilers | 3 |
| 2021-01-13 | Pittsburgh Penguins | 3 | Philadelphia Flyers | 6 |
| 2021-01-13 | Chicago Blackhawks | 1 | Tampa Bay Lightning | 5 |
| 2021-01-13 | Montreal Canadiens | 4 | Toronto Maple Leafs | 5 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

Answer (score 0):

```
table = soup.find('div', attrs = {'id':'div_games'})
trs = table.find_all('tr')
gamestats = []
for tr in trs:
  gamestat = {}
  gamestat['home_team_name'] = tr.find('td', attrs = {'data-stat' : 'home_team_name'})
  gamestat['visit_team_name'] = tr.find('td', attrs = {'data-stat' : 'visit_team_name'})
  gamestats.append(gamestat)
```